# URL rewrite phrase issues

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL that I wish to rewrite `mysite.com/accounts?id=test` should be directed to `mysite.com/accounts.php?id=test`. I've checked my `mod_rewrite`, it works, as other pages can be written correctly. I am currently trying this:

`RewriteRule ^accounts?([.]+)$ accounts.php?$1 [NC,L]`

This does not seem to work. Is it because of the question mark in the regular expression? I tried escaping it with \ but it still does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not lose the questionmark altogether and make the id either a subfolder or a page. Then the rule would be come something like: RewriteRule ^accounts/([.]+).html$ accounts.php?id=$1

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but why the dot between []? Is this not the same as `(.*)`? I think `RewriteRule ^accounts?(.*)$ accounts.php?$1 [NC,L]` should work.

Comment: @Rik, that sort of worked.. now at least the account.php file is found. (it used to give 404). Now in the first line I wrote die($_GET['id']) just to test, it returns blank. Any idea?

Comment: @l3utterfly I created an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i thought the `([.]+)` is the same as `(.*)`.

Second, RewriteRule already strips your query_string from the URL.
You can access it with `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

So your code would be

```
RewriteRule ^accounts?(.*)$ accounts.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

You can create an accounts.php with the following to test:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
exit();
// rest of your code
?>
```

and then check your `[QUERY_STRING]`.